# Cannot create .Net Core dev certificate on macOs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm able to successfully build my solution in Visual Studio however when I attempt to run, I'm seeing [HTTPS development certificate not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnIjt.png)

When I click Install and Trust I get a "dotnet dev-certs wants to make changes" popup. Soon after  I enter my password my project quits. When I try to run dotnet dev-certs https --trust in my terminal I get a "A valid HTTPS certificate is already present" even though I've deleted all localhost certs in my keychain. I've tried running a dotnet dev-certs https --clean, and I've tried unlocking, locking, and unlocking my keychain login again but no luck.

I'm on dotnet 5.0.100 and currently on macOs Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

You can always work without a certificate :

- Go to your project's options
- Go to the "ASP.NET CORE" tab
- under Run > Configuration, Remove "https://localhost:5001", leave
  http://localhost:5000

You should be able to work with the http://localhost:5000 URL and thus not worry about the certificate.

Comment: Went and gave that a try and now I'm just receiving a 404 or the project quits. Changed the url and appended '/api' at the end but no luck.